# How Do I Position Custom Dialog at specific Coordinate?

Tags: android, canvas, view, dialog, coordinates

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to figure out how to display the NewQuickAction3D popup dialog at a specific coordinate in a view.  I am integrating the popup with [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/05/map-touch-position-with-mask-version-ii.html) tutorial.  Essentially, I want to use the popup dialog to display data where the users touch instead painting on the canvas using "infoview"  Currently, the popup displays at the top&center of the view that I anchor it to.  How can i make it display a particular coordinate?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
public void updateMsg(String t_info, float t_x, float t_y, int t_c){
     infoView.updateInfo(t_info, t_x, t_y, t_c); //Infoview paints to on a specific coordinate
     quickAction.show(infoView); //How do I use the t_x & t_y coordinates here instead of just anchoring infoview
```

EDIT

```
public void updateMsg(String t_info, float t_x, float t_y, int t_c){
     infoView.updateInfo(t_info, t_x, t_y, t_c);
     WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = quickAction.getWindow().getAttributes(); //Error here getting window attributes
     wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
         wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
         wmlp.y = 100;   //y position
     quickAction.show(infoView);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Override onTouch() of your view

```
AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            showDialog();  // display dialog
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(dialog!=null)
              dialog.dismiss(); 
             // do something
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // do somethig
            break;
    }
    return true;
    } 
     public void showDialog()
      {

             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FingerPaintActivity.this);
             dialog = builder.create();
             dialog.setTitle("my dialog");
             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
             WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
         wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
             wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
             wmlp.y = 100;   //y position
         dialog.show();
      }
```

Even to draw user touches the screen then also dialog is displayed. so dismiss dialog in on move.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'm having some trouble with your answer.  NewQuickAction is a custom dialog so it won't allow me to get the window attributes.  any thoughts?

Comment: make your custom view inner class of your activity class